# state estimation by Dual Kalman Filter

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I want to estimate a variable x, and the observable variable y can be obtained from sensors. These two variables has an approximately linear relationship,i.e., y=k*x + b, but k and b are difficult to get, so I use two kalman filters, one for state (x) estimation, another for parameter (k,b) estimation, which actually combines the dual kalman filter. The general scheme and code in Python is as follows,

[the general scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyaJ1.png)

```
##Python code
#initialize state estimator
kf = KalmanFilter(dim_x=1,dim_z=1)
kf.x = numpy.array([x0])              # initial state
kf.F = numpy.array([1.])              # state transition matrix
kf.Q = 1000                           # state noise variance,
kf.R = 1                              # measurement noise variance

#initialize parameter estimator
dkf = KalmanFilter(dim_x=2,dim_z=1)
dkf.x = numpy.array([[-0.01,-0.1]]).T # initial state 
dkf.F = numpy.array([[1,0],
                    [0,1]])           # state transition matrix
dkf.Q = numpy.array([[1,0],
                    [0,1]])
dkf.R = 100                           # measurement noise variance

measurements = []
resultsDKF = []                                         #dual kalman filter state estimation result
ERRDKF = []                                               #estimation error

for i in xrange(N):   # N samples
    #### parameter estimator
    dkf.H = numpy.array([[kf.x,1]])   # measurement function
    y = Y[i]
    dkf.update(y,dkf.R,dkf.H)        
    dkf.predict()

    #### state estimator
    kf.H = numpy.array([dkf.x[0]])
    z = Y[i]-dkf.x[1] # Y[i]-b
    kf.update(z,kf.R,kf.H)    
    kf.predict()

    #### save data
    measurements.append(Y[i])
    resultsDKF.append (kf.x)
    ERRDKF.append(measurements[-1]-resultsDKF[-1])
```

the results are also followed:

[setting of initial state much away from true value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLQHt.png)

It seems that the predicted state varies with the true value, but there still is a big gap between predicted and true value.

I think the dual kalman filter doesn't really track true values of x, what's the  problem? Anybody who offers advice will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the power of the Kalman filter is that it develops and propagates correlations between the error's in the states.  By separating the problem into two filters, you preclude either filter from figuring out that there's an error it doesn't know about, because it's not modeled.  In the specific case you've described, where:

```
y=k*x + b
```

with k & b both unknown you should make x, k & b states of a single Kalman filter.  Over time with enough observations of a varying x (i.e. y measurements from different x values), the filter can observe k and b because of the correlation in the x, k, and b states carried in the covariance matrix.  With the 'x' filter separated from the 'k' and 'b' filter, it can remain offset forever, as in your result.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. But If I make x,k and b states of a single Kalman filter, how should I  write the measurement function in the standard KF form when k and x are supposed to multiply and then plus b to get y?  Another question is that, the dual Kalman filter was created to solve the problem of state and parameter estimation and reported to succeeded in many applications, where  there seems no error offset forever. Could you explain this in details? Thank you.

Comment: @Qiang1991 - Rereading this I disagree with my own answer.  The constant b is separable - but the product x*k is in every observation.  I don't think they can be separated in either a single or a dual Kalman filter.

Comment: As you say, the dual kalman filter was precluded due to an error that is not modeled. Then how do you think if I add a cross-term between two filters to present their mutual error, e.g.,  take the dkf.R in to account when calculating df.R. Do you have any advice for this method?Thank you.